# Need a faster way to build and debug Linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to debug my hardware,
compile latest Linux kernel (5.19.0-rc5) using regular steps.

```
make oldconfig
make -j16 bzImage
make -j16 modules
make modules_install && make install
```

New kernel is working almost fine, Except my SPI amplifiers.

I'm trying to debug it by modify some codes, mostly adding `printk` for example.

Then I do

```
make -j16 bzImage
make install
```

Now I cannot boot to my new kernel and get hundreds of messages like this.

```
Failed to validate module [xxx] BTF: -22
BPF: Invalid name
```

Is it those modules are not recognize the new `vmlinuz`?

I have to do `make clean` and rebuild with the full script above which consumes too much time even with the `-j16` (all of my cpu & threads).

What is better way to do this?

Comment: That's... weird. Unless you are editing build files e.g. Makefiles or other configuration files it should just re-compile the needed files and then the vmlinux. One point though: after re-compiling the kernel you should probably also re-compile and re-install the modules because they depend on the kernel. See if that helps.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, nothing weird. This is a self-test for modules. Since the kernel image has been changed and modules are not, this is the result. I have seen myself such an issue.